# Nginx random variables

Tags: variables, nginx, lua, webserver, openresty

Good morning programmers,
I'm trying to create random variables on nginx, (I have OpenResty nginx+lua).
Here is an example of a static variable:

```
set $teste 123;
```

So is it possible to turn this static variable random?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're using openresty, you can do it with the help of lua, for example (generating 3 digits):

```
set_by_lua_block $teste { return string.format('%03d', math.random(1, 999)) }
```

Comment: Without random seed the produced random sequence will be the same and thus totally predictable.

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide random seed, otherwise you'll get the same values each time the server is restarted.

There I use `resty.random.bytes` (that internally uses  [RAND_pseudo_bytes](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/RAND_pseudo_bytes.html) or [RAND_bytes](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/RAND_bytes.html) from OpenSSL) to provide <s>cryptographically strong</s> pseudo-random seed on nginx worker start.

UPD: You should use `resty_random.bytes(n, true)` for really *cryptographically strong* pseudo-random value. If the second argument is `true`, `RAND_bytes` will be used instead of `RAND_pseudo_byte`. But in this case you'll have to deal with possible exhaustion of the entropy pool. That is, `resty_random.bytes(n, true)` could return `nil` if there is no enough randomness to ensure an unpredictable byte sequence.

```
http {

    init_worker_by_lua_block {
        local resty_random = require('resty.random')
        -- use random byte (0..255 int) as a seed
        local seed = string.byte(resty_random.bytes(1))
        math.randomseed(seed)
    }

    server {
        listen 8888;

        location = / {
            set_by_lua_block $random {
                return math.random(1, 100)
            }

            echo "random number: $random";

        }
    }
}
```